# How to achieve 100,000 USD return annually

Tags: investing, investment-strategies

Assuming I need to achieve a return of 100,000 USD every year, what are my investment options?

Passive investment with low risk preferred, but open to other investment's strategies.

Comment: The same as everyone else's options. Look up an investment that matches your riskwillingness, and divide your expected pay through its yield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ycharts.com/indicators/moodys_seasoned_aaa_corporate_bond_yield

> US Corporate A Effective Yield:2.52% for Jan 22 2020

Thus, since `100000/2.52% = 3968253.97`, you need to buy $3,968,300 of high grade corporate bonds.

https://ycharts.com/indicators/us_corporate_bbb_effective_yield

> US Corporate BBB Effective Yield:3.03% for Jan 22 2020

Since junk bonds are yielding slightly more, using the same formula will show you that you'd need only $3,300,400.

Answer (score 0):

There is no investment that assures an overall return but only investments that assure an income that sets with or against a gain or loss of principal.

There are mortgageREIT and business-development-companies with dividends around 10%. And there are leveraged ETN's with dividends around 17%. (I wouldn't recommend energy MLP's but would recommend MLP ETN's that exclude energy.)

Someone could assist with setting up a covered-call-write operation. And there are  ETN's, ETF's, and closed-end-funds that write covered-calls. There are ETF's that hold the largest closed-end-funds. Someone could assist with setting up a leveraged forex income position.

I like dividend stocks with dividends around 5%. Commit to holding the stocks extremely long term and don't worry about fluctuation of principal while receiving current income. One quick way to judge these companies is to look at the debt-to-equity ratio.

Comment: Using a covered call strategy on a portfolio of diverse stocks tends to  lag in a bull market because the best stocks are taken away via assignment.  It's a form of adverse selection.  The strategy will tend to outperform (lose less) in a down market.  For these reasons, most closed end funds using this strategy have lagged  the market (SPY) since the end of the GFC.  If your stocks pay 5% in dividends, that's yield not return.

Comment: The investor might set up a GLD covered-call-write by thinking that the supply of gold will slowly decline while demand slowly increases. Or the investor might set up a TLT covered-call-write by thinking that the supply of Treasuries will slowly increase while demand just holds.

Comment: As for stock dividends, many companies have a payout ratio such that the dividend is a percentage of earnings.

Comment: The investor might write covered-calls on a stock index rather than write calls on all the individual stocks of a portfolio. Or the investor might choose which stocks to write covered calls on and which not to write.

Comment: The general flavor from posters here is that you cannot time the market and yet you suggest that an investor can succeed by writing covered calls on some stocks and not others.  That implies that he can do the equivalent of timing the market and do as well, if not even better than the market by not writing covered calls on his  really good stocks and writing them on the poorer stocks.  Well, not gonna happen.

Comment: As for suggesting that an investor can succeed by writing  CCs on other sectors such as GLD or TLT, well, that's more of the same.  If your investor can figure out "that the supply of gold will slowly decline while demand slowly increases" or he can figure out that "the supply of Treasuries will slowly increase while demand just holds" then he's quite the astute investor/trader and he shouldn't be wasting his time with covered calls... just as he shouldn't be wasting his time with covered call CEFs.

Comment: The one suggestion that you got right was to "write covered-calls on a stock index rather than write calls on all the individual stocks of a portfolio".  The BXMD 30 delta covered call index (on the SPX)  has slightly outperformed the SPX over the past 30+ years with a modestly  lower standard deviation.  And also,  many companies having a payout ratio such that the dividend is a percentage of earnings has nothing to do with the difference between Yield and Total Return.

Comment: Investors often follow a premise that is in the news. And that premise can gain or loose support as time goes on. It's not a very good viewpoint to say that investors should not use a logic. But with an on-going covered-call writing of a particular premise, I would recommend a systematic method of operation similar to ETN's and ETF's instead of the judgement of an individual.

Comment: There's no need to bump the subject so I will just comment that financial MLP ETN's no longer have the big-name private-equity companies because those companies have changed from LP's to corporations.